# AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded [Ubuntu Core 16]

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core, docker, apparmor

I have been wrestling with problem of running the docker snap on a Dell 5100 IoT Edge Gateway. I have another Dell Gateway - the 3001 - that does NOT face this issue.

Here are the steps that I carried out on the Dell 5100 Gateway:

Installed the Docker Snap, here is the output of 'snap list':

```
admin@localhost:~$ snap list
Name             Version          Rev  Developer   Notes
bluez            5.44-2           84   canonical   -
core             16.04.1          394  canonical   -
docker           17.03.1-ce-1     124  docker-inc  -
modem-manager    1.6.2-5          82   canonical   -
network-manager  1.2.2-10.2       166  canonical   -
snapweb          0.26.1           207  canonical   -
stlouis          16.04-1.13       11   canonical   -
stlouis-kernel   4.4.0-77-1       19   canonical   -
tpm2             1.0-4            18   canonical   -
uefi-fw-tools    1.4.1-0.7.2+git  7    canonical   -
```

After installing I ran the command stated in docker.help to enable the right snap interfaces:

```
sudo snap connect docker:home :home
```

Output of the 'snap interfaces' command after running the command in #2 above.

```
$ snap interfaces | grep docker
:docker-support           docker:privileged,docker:support
:firewall-control         docker
:home                     docker
:network                  docker,snapweb,tpm2,uefi-fw-tools
:network-bind             docker,snapweb,tpm2
docker:docker-daemon      docker:docker-cli
admin@localhost:~$
```

I then checked the apparmor status for docker using the following command:

Unlike what I see in the 3001 Output for the same command, `docker-default` is missing:

```
$ sudo aa-status | grep docker
   snap.docker.compose
   snap.docker.docker
   snap.docker.dockerd
   snap.docker.help
   snap.docker.dockerd (1582)
   snap.docker.dockerd (1627)
```

Here is the OUTPUT from the Dell 3001 gateway for the apparmor status and the snap list:

The big difference between the 3001 and 5100 is the OS version - I am very new to Ubuntu Core and cannot figure out why docker-default is missing in the apparmor status. I have rebooted, factory-restored and tried many other thing. The problem that manifests is as follows:

I am able to pull an image, and that works, I used the following command:

```
sudo docker pull eclipse-mosquitto:1.4.10
```

The image gets pulled, but when I try to run it:

```
$ sudo docker run -d -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 --name mqtt -t eclipse-mosquitto:1.4.10
d11e29c04064ea3c546c6c9141abae73508dd2cc98492860accb4461af40b661
docker: Error response from daemon: AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded...
```

I also tried to run it with the no confinement policy, then I get an `oci runtime error`:

```
$ sudo docker run -d --security-opt apparmor=noconfinement -p 1883:1883 -p 9001:9001 --name mqtt -t
eclipse-mosquitto:1.4.10
fe501196f9ac0d27e82b43069aafee4c806d80c1ae9ce363040b96996d74f963
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused
"process_linux.go:258: applying cgroup configuration for process caused \"mkdir /var/lib/snapd/hostfs/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/docker: permission denied\"".
```

Note that the same steps on the Dell 3001 Gateway do not have these two issues outlined above.

Comment: time to file a bug report ;)

Comment: snap interfaces is deprecated: `snap connections | grep docker`

Answer (score 2):

First, apologies for not receiving any reply to your very important issue. As a note to others who may run into this same issue, the main crux of the issue was that the core snap on the 3001 where docker would run successfully was at a newer core snap version, whereas on the 5100, the core snap was stuck at the same outdated version that shipped with the factory Ubuntu Core image. The outdated version had an issue that made receiving newer versions of the core snap not function correctly. The issue has been resolved on the Ubuntu Store side so that this older core snap can be updated to the latest validated version, so this particular issue should not affect anyone else.

Also, for future reference, I'd like to point you to the [snapcraft.io forums](https://forum.snapcraft.io/) where everything snaps and Ubuntu Core are discussed.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually missing the `--security-opt seccomp:unconfined` option and the `-v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro` bind mount (both of them make no sense when using the docker snap since it already runs completely confined) so using:

```
--security-opt apparmor:unconfined --security-opt seccomp:unconfined -v /sys/fs/cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
```

is the right thing to do here ... the snap confinement wrapped around the docker executable will take care of security.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look good as that is a very old version of the core snap.
Basically, this issue happened once and was reported by Dell representative 5 months ago.

To fix it.

1. Please run the following command to keep all snaps up to date

   ```
   sudo snap refresh
   ```
2. If you hit the problem as follows when updating the core snap from the brand store

   ```
   Error cannot refresh "core" :cannot refresh "core" to  revision xxxx: no validation by "xxxxxx"
   ```

   That means core snap is not validated yet although it's been qualified. However, you can still get it updated with `--ignore-validation` option by running:

   ```
   sudo snap refresh core --ignore-validation
   ```

As Jim recommended, all snap and ubuntu-core related discussions nowadays moved to [snapcraft.io](https://forum.snapcraft.io/]) forum. It's the preferred place for snappy discussion where you always get timely feedback.

Comment: The first thing that I had tried was to refresh the snaps in fact it was clear to me that the versions were different BUT the snaps wouldn't update and it was after that I posted this entry. I tried updating the snaps - and that has now taken care of the issue. (It was interesting that the snap refresh - even though it updated the snaps failed to indicate a status message saying something to the effect "the following snaps were refreshed"

Comment: Yes, the status message looks really confused to end users. I think that's something store needs to improve on the status message when people don't get snaps updated after refreshing.

Comment: NOTE / UPDATE  - Well docker runs on the Gateways however on both the 5000 and 3000 - I cannot build images on the Gateways anymore. When I use the "sudo docker build ....." I basically run into the 'can't stat' error :) So far not able to get it to bypass or fix this issue.

Comment: You hit the apparmor denials(dac-override-denied).                                    
It's been discussed on the forum https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/docker-load-fails-with-permission-denied/1227/3                                                                      What you need to do is 1. make home plug connected if you put your docker project under $HOME 2. make sure docker project folder and files owned by root i.e Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml. Here is how I build an image with docker snap on the ubuntu core http://paste.ubuntu.com/25814535/

Comment: Ok - that worked - I tried it out and I can build images on the Dell 5000 Gateway now!!